# Average groups of rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have something like the following in Excel:

```
Group  Rate
1      20%
2      35%
3      31%
3      24%
3      25%
1      15%
3      22%
4      50%
2      50%
2      32%
```

I would like to calculate the average per group, resetting each time a new group number is found.

e.g.:

```
Group  Rate   Final_Rate
1      20%    20%
2      35%    35%
3      31%    26.67%
3      24%    26.67%
3      25%    26.67%
1      15%    15%
3      22%    22%
4      50%    50%
2      50%    41%
2      32%    41%
```

In other words, for rows which have the same Group that follow one another directly, I would like to have the average of the rate of each of those rows for the group.

Assume the values for Group and Rate are populated in columns A and B respectively.

I tried writing some dummy code.

```vb
Sub Calculate_Funny_Average()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    
    
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Each rw In sh.Rows
    
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value <> "" Then
        
            If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        
            Cur_Group = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value
            Cur_Rate = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4)
            
            Next_Group = sh.Cells(rw.Row + 1, 1).Value
            
            Do While Cur_Group = Next_Group
                    
                'Something ??
            
            Loop
            
        End If
        
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: @braX - I've added some skeleton work of what I've tried. Apologies I'm not too experienced with VBA. I'm not entirely sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: You can use AVERAGEIF to do it without VBA

Comment: @DarrellH - I thought about that, but the problem is then I do not know how to reset it. For example, if the same group number comes back later on, but is not repeated in that particular instance, whereas something like AVERAGEIF will simply give me the overall average for the group, not particular the "current repeated selection" of the group.

Comment: @DarrellH , or am I possibly missing something? Can you please show me the AVERAGEIF which would provide the necessary? I will happily accept as an answer. More than happy to not use VBA if not needed.

Comment: With Office 365: `=AVERAGE(XLOOKUP(TRUE,$A$1:A2<>A2,$B$2:B3,,0,-1):XLOOKUP(TRUE,A2:A$1040000<>A2,B1:B$1039999))`

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim arr
Dim i As Integer, m As Integer, x As Integer
arr = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'catch all data to an array. Make sure there are headers Group, Rate and Final Rate

For i = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr) 'loop all rows, without the header
arr(i, 3) = CDbl(arr(i, 2)) 'the first one must be recorded. cdbl() converts to Double type
x = 1 'x will be the times the group is repeated
If i + x <= UBound(arr) Then 'ifthe row + times the group appears is bigger than number of data rows,quit looping, else
    Do While arr(i, 1) = arr(i + x, 1) 'while the group below is the same as the "i"
        arr(i, 3) = arr(i, 3) + CDbl(arr(i + x, 2)) 'record the value + the value below
        x = x + 1 'add +1 to x to see the next row
        If i + x > UBound(arr) Then 'again, if is i + x is bigger than the array, quit
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End If
    For m = x - 1 To 0 Step -1 'now, let's divide. Step-1 is to keep the original number and for the last one being changed
        arr(i + m, 3) = arr(i, 3) / x
        'if you want, record the value with %
        arr(i + m, 3) = Format(arr(i + m, 3), "0.00 %")
    Next m
    
    i = i + x - 1
Next i
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))) = arr 'print the array over the original range
End Sub
```

Comment: One comment, unqualified ranges(ranges without the parent sheet dictated) are usually frowned upon in answers.  It is one of the problems that pops up a lot around here.  But I do like the use of arrays to iterate.  Even if you simple put `ActiveSheet.` in front of your ranges it is more acceptable than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

One method of using a formula involves adding a helper column.
The helper column will change value when the "Group" changes.

I put the helper column elsewhere on the worksheet, but you can put it where-ever you wish, and/or hide it

***Helper Column***

```
    E2: 1
    E3: =IF($A3=A2,E2,E2+1)
```

*and fill down*

***Final_Rate***

```
C2:  =AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11,Sheet1!$E$2:$E$11,Sheet1!$E2)
```

*and fill down*

[image]

*If you have Office 365 with the `XLOOKUP`, you can use the more complicated formula mentioned by @ScottCraner in the comments and avoid the helper column.*